# SWIFTUI : prevent keyboard dismissal on pressing return key in TextField

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield

I am using TextField in SwiftUI. and on pressing return key keyboard dismiss itself.

Is there any way to keep the keyboard up and still keep TextField editable position.

Thanks

Comment: Have your tried multiline textfield?

Comment: Using multiline text field actually works (iOS 16+)

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround that works on iOS 15+, but it will still create a bounce animation of your keyboard.

If you have multiple textfields, you can use **enum** with *@FocusState* instead **Bool**.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState var focused: Bool
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text", text: $text)
            .focused($focused)
            .onSubmit {
                focused = true
            }
    }
}
```

To achieve better solution without bouncing keyboard, I suggest great third party library [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect):

```
import Introspect

class TextFieldKeyboardBehavior: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var textFieldKeyboardBehavior = TextFieldKeyboardBehavior()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text", text: $text)
            .introspectTextField { textField in
                textField.delegate = textFieldKeyboardBehavior
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution bounces indeed even on iOS 16, Introspect did the trick.

Comment: Hmm but how can you detect when a [Return] was pressed in order to execute the `onSubmit` code? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77212497/prevent-keyboard-for-textfield-from-dismissing-after-a-return-but-need-to-dete

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to expand on @Ivo's answer in response to @Barrrdi's comment.

My UITextFieldDelegate looks something like this:

```
class TextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var shouldReturn: (() -> Bool)?
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        if let shouldReturn = shouldReturn {
            return shouldReturn()
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Then my SwiftUI view might look like this:

```
import Introspect

struct TestView: View {
    
    enum FocusedField {
        case username, password
    }
    
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var usernameFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate()
    var passwordFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate()
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            TextField(text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
                .introspectTextField(customize: { textField in
                    
                    usernameFieldDelegate.shouldReturn = {
                        
                        if usernameIsValid() {
                            focusedField = .password
                        }
                        
                        return false
                    }
                    
                    textField.delegate = usernameFieldDelegate
                })
            
            SecureField(text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
                .introspectTextField(customize: { textField in
                    
                    passwordFieldDelegate.shouldReturn = {
                        validateAndProceed()
                        
                        return false
                    }
                    
                    textField.delegate = passwordFieldDelegate
                })
        }
    }
    
    func usernameIsValid() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func validateAndProceed() {}
}
```

The important thing in avoiding the bounce is textFieldShouldReturn() needs to return false (however you want to achieve this).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NotAPhoenix [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224531/swiftui-prevent-keyboard-dismissal-on-pressing-return-key-in-textfield/75865891#comment113573442_64224531) I decided to give it a try.

So if you are using iOS 16+, you can actually use multiline text field and intercept the new line character, then react accordingly.

Here is an example with 3 text fields, where you move from first to second to third and then close the keyboard.

```
enum Field {
  case one
  case two
  case three
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var one = ""
  @State private var two = ""
  @State private var three = ""

  @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      TextField("1", text: $one, axis: .vertical)
        .focused($focusedField, equals: .one)
        .submitLabel(.next)
        .onChange(of: one, perform: { [oldValue = one] value in
          if value.last == "\n" {
            focusedField = .two
            one = oldValue
          }
        })

      TextField("2", text: $two, axis: .vertical)
        .focused($focusedField, equals: .two)
        .submitLabel(.next)
        .onChange(of: two, perform: { [oldValue = two] value in
          if value.last == "\n" {
            focusedField = .three
            two = oldValue
          }
        })


      TextField("3", text: $tree, axis: .vertical)
        .focused($focusedField, equals: .tree)
        .submitLabel(.send)
        .onChange(of: three, perform: { [oldValue = three] value in
          if value.last == "\n" {
            focusedField = nil
            tree = oldValue
          }
        })

    }
    .padding()
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
  }
}
```